# Установка NumPy и Python

Tags: python

Как можно установить NumPy на Python 3.7 без наличия интернета на компьютере?

Comment: Ммм, никак?????

Answer (score 4):

Я не ставил конкретно `NumPy`, но смысл схожий.

1. Нужно скачать сам пакет на https://pypi.org/, найти его через поиск.
2. NumPy там лежит whl пакетом, потому сначала нужно будет установить `wheel`. Найдите его на pypi.org и скачайте файл .tar.gz. Установите его простой командой `pip install полный_путь_до_имени_файла` в консоли, подробнее описано как это сделать на [официальном сайте](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#installing-packages). Если выдаст ошибку, то нужно будет посмотреть каких пакетов не хватает, это будет указано в ошибке. Докачать их и установить их таким же способом.
3. Таким образом установить сначала `wheel`, затем `NumPy`. Но все входящие пакеты нужно будет докачивать по одному.

Советую класть их все вместе в одну папку, чтобы менять только названия пакета и не менять путь.

Comment: Еще с гита можно скачать https://github.com/numpy/numpy

Answer (score 1):

PIP [позволяет скачивать](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/) пакеты вместе со всеми зависимостями и после установить их локально.

Таким образом для переноса пакета со всеми зависимостями с онлайн-машины (с установленным python) на машину без доступа к Интернету следует:

1. Убедиться, что версия `python` на обоих машинах совпадает,

   ```
   python --version
   ```
2. Создать директорию для необходимых пакетов:

   ```
   mkdir dist  
   cd dist
   ```
3. Скачать пакеты:

   ```
   pip download <package name>
   ```
4. Перенести директорию на оффлайн-машину, используя любой носитель информации,
5. Установить зависимости из [локальной директории](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/#no-index):

   ```
   pip install --no-index --find-links=/path/to/dist_directory
   ```

---

Ситуация усложняется, если онлайн-машина и целевая машина имеют разные версии `python` или `ОС`.
В случае с разными версиями `python` можно создать отдельный `venv` и [указать нужную версию](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv) перед началом скачивания.

Более сложный вариант, который точно подойдет, если онлайн и целевая машины имеют разные ОС:

1. Скачать пакеты на онлайн-машине при помощи `pip download`,
2. Найти среди скаченных пакетов те, в названии которых явно содержится версия `python` и\или `ОС`. Например: numpy-1.18.1-`cp36-cp36m-win32`.whl,
3. Найти в репозитории [PyPI](https://pypi.org/) пакеты, которые имеют привязку к версии, и скачать их,
4. Подменить скачанные пакеты в директории `dist`,
5. Продолжить с 4 пункта предыдущей инструкции.